# Error: Open two cameras at the same time in Python - OPENCV (Pycharm) - error (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, ip-camera

happy day, I am trying to synchronize two cameras
(my local computer) and the camera of my cell phone with IP Web cam,
however when running the code it generates an error and the two
cameras that I have previously opened are closed (see photo ). What
would this be due to? Thanks for your help!

ERROR -->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\JUCABALL\Desktop\camera_stream_openCV-master\main.py", line 20, in <module>
     cv2.imshow ('cam1', frame1)
cv2.error: OpenCV (4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp: 182:
error: (-215: Assertion failed)! _src .empty () in function 'cv :: cvtColor'
```

This is the tabs - after fews seconds tabs close

[Tabs, 2 cameras][1]

This is my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


# capture the webcam
vid1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
vid2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
vid3 = cv2.VideoCapture(
    "http://192.168.0.11:8080/video", cv2.CAP_DSHOW
)  # ipwebcam address


while True:  # while true, read the camera
    ret, frame = vid1.read()
    ret1, frame1 = vid2.read()
    ret2, frame2 = vid3.read()

    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("cam0", frame)  # frame with name and variable of the camera
        cv2.imshow("cam1", frame1)
        cv2.imshow("cam3", frame2)

    # to break the loop and terminate the program
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

vid1.release()
vid2.release()
vid3.release()
```

Comment: this seems about the problem can not get frames from camera. Are you able to get stream via on VLC or any other tool with the same ipwebcam adress ? Try to run cameras by one by and figure out which camera causes problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not checking the value of `ret1` and `ret2`.

If those are `False`, the images will not have been captured, and you're still trying to show them, and OpenCV crashes because there's no way to show an image that doesn't exist.

Try

```
if ret:
    cv2.imshow("cam0", frame)
if ret1:
    cv2.imshow("cam1", frame1)
if ret2:
    cv2.imshow("cam3", frame2)
```

instead.

You could also store all of the capture devices in a list, and all the captured images equally so, to make the code a little simpler to work with:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

captures = [
    cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW),
    cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW),
    cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.0.11:8080/video", cv2.CAP_DSHOW),  # ipwebcam address
]


while True:  # while true, read the camera
    frames = []
    for cap in captures:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frames.append((frame if ret else None))

    for i, frame in enumerate(frames):
        if frame is not None:  # None if not captured
            cv2.imshow(f"cam{i}", frame)

    # to break the loop and terminate the program
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break

for cap in captures:
    cap.release()
```

Comment: Thks @AKX  but I tried this before and the problem is that only open one tab "cam0"

Comment: That would mean that the other cameras don't capture any frames. Why that might happen is an entirely different question, though.

Comment: I tried the last recommendation and appears that the "i" is ambigous  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JUCABALL\Desktop\camera_stream_openCV-master\atest.py", line 18, in <module>
    if frame:  # None if not captured
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Oops, yep, that'd be `if frame is not None`. OpenCV returns empty matrices, not none, if the camera is not read.

Comment: Even if in the frame arrangement I put 0,1,2 something similar to the main code happens, the tabs open and close again immediately

Comment: I got it, then the problem is my camera it's not ok,  I'm going to wirting this part in a new question if it's the case, Thks a lot